# Redundant modelling is acceptable in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

New to Graph DBs and data modelling.
I know that there's no restrictions on Neo4J on this particular case but would like to understand if this is a crazy thing to do.

In other NOSQL (Columnar, Document) stores, we typically model the same data in multiple collections so as to gain performance/functional benefits ie we trade the storage off for performance and functional gains.

Is this also an approach that people follow in Neo4J or is it completely unheard of?

For example we come up with a model today and if we come across a new requirement for which the existing model is not a fit (and modifying this is expensive), is it recommended to create another model with certain portions duplicated (more suited for this specific use case).

I know Neo4J supports transactions and writes could be wrapped in a transaction so that the data is consistent.

Is this considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: Note that refactoring a model is fairly common, so if the current model isn't working out it does make sense to start making changes so that the queries become easier or more efficient. And in the course of evaluation, there's no reason why you couldn't have some redundant data so you could make your comparisons, and clean up the no-longer-needed parts later.

Answer (score 1):

Storing redundant data is an anti-pattern if it is unnecessary. It only seems to be needed when a time-critical use case simply cannot wait for traversal to a single source of truth.

Since graph databases make it very easy to reuse a node by simply adding a relationship, it should be very rare that the addition of a new use case requires the duplication of existing data to new nodes.